Running multiple Google Apps scripts sequentially (one after another)
I am working on a sheet that pulls data from an API, then runs calculations on it. Because of timeouts and limitations, I need to run one script, wait for the calculations to finish, then run another one.
Is there a way to have the sheet (or script) wait to run one function until a cell in the sheet shows a specific value? (this is my workaround)
CONTEXT
I do a little spreadsheet work for my wife's summer camp, and they want to get daily updates on the number of campers. Their CRM (campminder) has an API, which I am calling to get a variety of information:

An API key (Get_Key)
An updated list of all campers (Get_Campers)
Details on each individual camper (Get_Camper_Details)

So the order of operations is:

Run Get_Key
WAIT until Get_Key has fully (and successfully) executed, THEN run Get_Campers
WAIT until Get_Campers has fully (and successfully) executed, THEN drop a Get_Camper_Details formula (IMPORTAPI function) next to each camper_id. AFAIK, there's no way to get camper details in a batch.
WAIT until Get_Camper_Details has fully (and successfully) executed for each camper, THEN copy all the details to a new sheet and delete the IMPORTAPI formulas so they don't constantly recalculate.

I have gotten all of the steps above to run properly when I watch and wait, but I would love to automate this - ideally on a timer, but at the very least in a way that one button click will run all four steps in sequence.
Is there a way to do this within Apps Script?
Thanks!
JSB
I have gotten all of the steps above to run properly when I watch and wait, but I would love to automate this - ideally once a day (timed), but at the very least in a way that one button click will run all four steps in sequence.
I've also looked at this answer, which will run the functions in sequence but NOT wait for the specific outcome.
I HAVE set up a counter to tell me when it's safe to run the final (copy/delete) function. I could use that as the trigger for the final one.

This question needs more focus. If you are going to implement your design using Google Apps Script, the first thing that you should decide is the type of Apps Script project to use, a bound script or a stand alone script. Then you might want to first to learn about URL Fetch Service (Class UrlFetchApp) to make the calls to the CRM API. Take a look to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/. Depending on your background you might want to start by the concepts section, the samples section, etc.

One of the key factors to have in mind is the execution time limit. In example , custom function  and simple triggers have a 30 secs time limit, but functions run from a UI or from the script editor and installable triggers has a 6 or 30 minutes execution time limit.

Thanks, @Wicket. I'm using a third-party extension (API Connector) to make the API calls.

Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned in my previous comment, this question needs more focus. Please bear in mind that questions on this site should be about a specific problem that is unique to programming.

Mmm, the limitations and quota of Google Sheets are quite a complication. What I've done (as you mentioned in your workaround) is have a cell with the step in which I am and continue from that place.
So, you can have an installable trigger set on a minute timer with a function called "stageChecker" or as you wish. It checks the stage and if it says "Stop" it ends, if it says "Get_Key", "Get_Campers", "Get_Camper_Details" it runs those functions, and if it says "Running" it also ends so it means that another of those three functions are running. So, each of the functions could have a starting and ending clause that changes that specific cell to "Running" and the name of the corresponding next stage.
Something like this:
function stageChecker() {
  // Open the active spreadsheet and get the stage value from a specific cell
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Control"); // Sheet where the stage is stored
  var stageCell = sheet.getRange("A1"); // Adjust cell reference
  var stage = stageCell.getValue(); // Get the current stage

  switch(stage) {
    case "Stop":
      // Stop the process if the stage is "Stop"
      Logger.log("Process stopped.");
      return;

    case "Get_Key":
      // Call the function to get the key
      Logger.log("Getting Key...");
      getKey(); // Your function to get the key
      break;

    case "Get_Campers":
      // Call the function to get campers
      Logger.log("Getting Campers...");
      getCampers(); // Your function to get campers
      break;

    case "Get_Camper_Details":
      // Call the function to get camper details
      Logger.log("Getting Camper Details...");
      getCamperDetails(); // Your function to get camper details
      break;

    case "Running":
      // If the stage says "Running," do nothing (since another function is already executing)
      Logger.log("Process is already running.");
      return;

    default:
      Logger.log("Unknown stage: " + stage);
      return;
  }

}

For example, getKey():
function getKey() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var stageCell = sheet.getRange("A1")
  stageCell.setValue("Running")

  //The rest of your code


  stageCell.setValue("Get_Campers")
}

And you can set your final function to change value to Stop, and only run again "getKey" once and the rest will continue minute by minute from that stage. Let me know if it was clear :)

Thank you, @Martin. I'm not sure how to provide an example sheet without going through the hassle of anonymizing the data somehow.

What challenge have you faced?

I've got the StageChecker working in a manual, stepped fashion, but I am still wondering how to get it to run together, with one button push.
Essentially, I want it to run like this:

GetKey - then wait until it's done
GetCampers - then wait until that's done
GetCamperData - then wait until that's done AND all of the lines have run their individual calls
CopyInfo

Is there a way to do that?

Mmm, I hope to get myself clear in English... the main idea is that you have a trigger (stageChecker) set once in a minute that will see all day and all night long what needs to be done by checking this reference cell ("A1" in my example). So, when you're not using the spreadsheet, you'll have the order "Stop" in A1, and the trigger will check and do nothing... when you click your button it will run GetKey, Let's say you do it at 1:30:00 PM. GetKey will change A1 to "Running" at 1:30:02 and finally to "GetCampers" at 1:32:33 PM. So, at 1:33:00 the trigger will be run as always but..,

the cell in A1 will be "GetCampers" so GetCampers will be run at 1:33:00 PM, then change A1 to "Running" and at 1:37:42 PM it will change A1 to "GetCamperData"... so when stageChecker triggers at 1:38:00 PM A1 will say "GetCamperData" and GetCamperData will be run. That function will change A1 to "Running" at 1:38:02 PM and to "CopyInfo" at 1:43:06 PM... so, when stageChecker runs at 1:44:00 PM it will run CopyInfo, which would change A1 to "Running" and finally to "Stop" at 1:48:35 PM... so, from that moment on, the trigger won't do nothing until you press the button...

... and the cycle starts again. I hope it's clear how each of the functions would be run sequentally thanks to A1 and the minute-set trigger of stageChecker - obviously, you can change A1 to the cell you desire. Let me know if it was clearer. So, the functions won't be run EXACTLY when the previous one finishes, but would have (in the worst scenario) 59 seconds of delay in between until the trigger is run again
